# How do I fix problems with server certificate for Sending SMTP Mails on UiPath?

Tags: automation, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying to use UiPath to **Send SMTP Mail Message**.

For my gmail account I am using those detailes:

```
Port: 587
Server: "smtp.gmail.com"
SecureConnection: StartTlsWhenAvailable
```

I have less secure apps allowed, there are no typos + I've already tried this with Python script and it works.

However, on UiPath Studio I always got this error:

```
An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

The server’s SSL certificate could not be validated for the following reasons:
• The server certificate has the following errors:
• The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

I am glad for any tips. Thanks.

Comment: Is your code behind a proxy or a particularly restrictive firewall?

Comment: I think behind a firewall.

Comment: The firewall may be blocking access to port 587.  465 is another choice though your client needs to support SSL.  The fact though that the certificate can't be validated makes me think it's a firewall blocking and, perhaps, redirecting.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Sadly 465 has the same error. Are there any other options I should try?

Comment: I'm not sure of your environment but if you can run a command line from the same place you're running your code from you can do something like `openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp-relay.gmail.com:587` or `openssl s_client -connect smtp-relay.gmail.com:465`.  You'll get a bunch of output but the last line should be a "2xx" status (i.e. 250 or 220 is what I got) meaning that the SMTP server is ready to "talk".  If you don't get that it might help you debug what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to install `openssl` on the environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Firewall was the problem. I disabled it for the run and it works. It's not perfect, but better then nothing. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your virus scanner temporarily and try again. It should work.